# Allow end user to enter ruby code that I execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a rails app and there are two fairly important models, being Reminder and Matcher.

```
class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Reminders allow a user to set their own schedule to do something, so I have a text field called "condition" and I allow them to enter their own ruby code.

For example they can enter:

```
Date.today.friday?
```

If they want a reminder every Friday. I have done it like this to allow ultimate flexibility in the way users can create their own reminders.

Then I have a scheduled cron task, that loops through all of the Reminders and checks their condition and actions them, as in:

```
For reminder in Reminder.all
  if eval(reminder.condition)
    # do something
  end
end
```

The other use case for this method is there I use conditions in a Matcher Model, and this is a harder one to explain but I actually allow the user to access associated model data in that condition, for example the condition might be:

```
@matcher.parent.name == "Father" && @matcher.parent.children.count < 10
```

I know it's very scary to `eval` something the user has input, so I am doing some validation on the model to prevent a few "nasty" words like "delete, destroy, etc". I have build a small inplace code editor with some menu's that insert code into an ACE editor.

I love the way this works as it allows the user ultimate flexibility.

How could this be implemented without using eval?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot trust user input. Blocking certain words will not block the more imaginative techniques like send["d-e-s-t-r-o-y".split('-').join('')] or worse.

An improvement you can make, if you really want to do it, is eval it remotely within a hardened virtual machine on a different user account and verify that the output of stdout of that command matches a date format. Even that people can get around if you allow any code execution.

For the more powerful code you should be writing a DSL of explicit things you want to allow. Whitelist is more secure than blacklist because nobody is smart enough to beat the rest of the world's imagination combined.

Comment: Thats a fantastic example, and one I have not considered. I am keen to go down the path of writing a DSL but I've not done that before. Can you elaborate at all before I start researching the steps involved to create a DSL?